# Disable multiple options from dropdown list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have following options in dropdown list.

```
<select>

   <option value="FRUIT">FRUIT</option>
   <option value="MANGO">MANGO</option>
   <option value="APPLE">APPLE</option>
   <option value="BANANA">BANANA</option>

  <option value="GRADES">GRADES</option>
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
   <option value="C">C</option>

</select>
```

I want to disable(readonly) FRUIT and GRADES permanently. How can I achieve this result using javascript ?

Comment: It depends on the action after clicking on the event. In .NET I have a default value of 'abc123' when it's say "Selection Option" do I know not to process it. What is your post user click action?

Comment: If you want to disable it permanently then it's waste to use javascript for it. Use HTML `optgroup` and you don't have to worry about javascript. I provided solution below

Answer (score 1):

You should use "disabled" attribute. 
For example:

```
<option value="FRUIT" disabled>FRUIT</option>
<option value="GRADES" disabled>GRADES</option>
```

**If you are using jQuery in your page, so follow the below codes:**

```
<script> 
   function myFunction() { 
     document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled = true; 
   } 
</script>
```

**Your html code should be like:**

```
<option id="mySelect" value="FRUIT" disabled>FRUIT</option> 
<option id="mySelect" value="GRADES" disabled>GRADES</option>
```

Comment: Using attribute it's working but as per my requirement javascript function is required to do the same

Comment: <script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled = true;
}
</script>

Comment: Use below codes: <script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled = true;
}
</script> Your html code should be like: <option id="mySelect" value="FRUIT" disabled>FRUIT</option>

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="selectField"> <option value="FRUIT" disabled>FRUIT</option>
             <option value="MANGO">
              MANGO
             </option>
             <option value="APPLE">
             APPLE
</option>
             <option value="BANANA">BANANA</option>

             <option value="GRADES" disabled>GRADES</option>
             <option value="A">A</option>
             <option value="B">B</option>
             <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

hope so this one helps.just try this one!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `optgroup` inside select. The `<optgroup>` is used to group related options in a drop-down list. Chek [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp).

Your example should be like

```css
optgroup[readonly] {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  color: #555555;
}
```

```html
<select>
      <optgroup label="FRUIT" readonly="readonly">        
        <option value="MANGO">MANGO</option>
        <option value="APPLE">APPLE</option>
        <option value="BANANA">BANANA</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="GRADES" disabled="disabled">  
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
```

Also `readonly` options are still submittable.